# Prove that given points are colinear

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I am very new at analytic geometry and this question may be very easy but I am literally stuck.

> Let $SABC$ be a tetrahedron, and let $A’,B’,C’$ be arbitrary points of the edges $SA,SB,SC$ respectively. Let $M$ be the intersection point of the planes $A’BC, B’CA, C’AB$, and $N$ be the intersection point of the planes $AB’C’, BC’A’,CA’B’$. Show that M, N and S are collinear points.

Is it enough to show that M and N are scaler times S? I am not sure about what should I do and I cannot imagine the figure.

Sorry for this question and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Almost. That would be the case only if the $MNS$ line would go through the origin. In most general case, show that $M-S=k(N-S)$, with $k$ being a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Define $D = C'N\cap SAB(A'B')$
Because of plane $C'NA'B$, $DA'B$ is a line, same for $DB'A$
Meaning $D=B'A\cap A'B$
Notice the same argument implies $CM\cap SAB(A'B')=B'A\cap A'B = C'N\cap SAB(A'B')$
meaning $CM$ intersects $C'N$ which implies $CC'MN$ is a plane which contains $S$ because of line $CC'S$.
by the same argument we have plane $BB'MNS$.
the intersection of these two planes is the $MNS$ line desired.